# In Java, how do I declare a matrix (properly)? How do I pass matrix to function which expects a vector?

Tags: java, android, matrix, parameters

I'm doing my babysteps in Java and Android APIs. Currently, I'm stuck with retrieving platform orientation matrices using [`SensorManager.getRotationMatrix`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float[],%20float[],%20float[],%20float[]%29) because my data is `float[][]` while function expects `float[]`.

```
float [] [] R, I = // { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } } ;
        new float [3] [3];
float [] gravity, geomagnetic = new float [3];

manager.getRotationMatrix( R, I, gravity, geomagnetic );
```

Likewise, an another method of the same class [`void getRotationMatrixFromVector (float[] R, float[] rotationVector)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrixFromVector%28float[],%20float[]%29) again expects `float[]` while `R` is clearly supposed to be `float[][]`. Do I miss some trick allowing to go without unwinding matrix to vector? Please advise.

Comment: When i worked with sensor i declare R and I like 
 float R[] = new float[9];
 float I[] = new float[9];
There are no 2-demensional matrices

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten a 2d array then you can iterate over it and add it to an `ArrayList`. Then you can use `toArray()` to get an array from the `ArrayList`.

Other option is to multiply the number of rows and columns in your 2d array to find the number of elements and then iterate over the 2d array to fill data in 1d array.